# Contact form in node

Tags: nodes, forms

I have a product catalogue website with no commerce feature and i want to embed a contact form in every product(node). User will be able to fill that form and the owner of the website will receive an email which will also includes the title and the link of the specific node. Is there any module available that can do this?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using d6 or d7?

Answer (score 1):

[Node feedback](https://drupal.org/project/node_feedback) module offers a check box on the node form asking the author to allow the visitors of the node to send feedback/request for the node using the personal/site wide contact form. It is also possible to view URL from which node, for that you have set token. See the below image, possible to set available fields token.

[image]

For Drupal 6:

[Author Contact](https://drupal.org/project/authorcontact) shows a contact form that contacts the author of the current node.
You can set the tokens for title to show in email as well as in fields. I am using this in my [website](http://www.richtown.ae/?q=content/spacious-3-bed-maid-jumeirah-park-legacy-small-style) see the Interested in this Property

Comment: Node feedback might was good solution but there is a bug for D7 wich can be found here https://drupal.org/node/2031139 and i am not sure if i can use custom fields with it

Answer (score 1):

The module [Contact Form On Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_form_on_node) exactly says what it does, so please give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Webforms + Nodeblock would work. Enable both modules & allow the Webform content type to be shown as a block, then configure the block to display only on your selected nodes.

Comment: With weforms + nodeblock is it possilbe for administrator to receive the Node Title and URL when user submits the form?

Comment: Sure- just add the Rule. It works like a normal webform, but displays as a block instead of page.

Comment: I have set up the rule and added the related tokens but what happens is to get the title of the Webform and not the title of the Current page(product) where the webform is displayed as a block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the way to insert contact form in node.

1. You can use [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module to insert any type of form in node. Webform provide you the flexibility to add as many forms with any number of fields in form with the availability of form created as block.
   Now this module can be assigned to any node using its visibility settings
2. You can use [Form block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module which created block availability of contact form . so it can be assigned any node.
3. Or can call the contact form programmatically using the below code in  any custom block using php.

Hope it will help!

```
  <?php

          module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');
          echo drupal_render(drupal_get_form('contact_site_form'));     ?>
```